# How to show ID field as readonly in Edit Form, of a sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, sharepoint-list

I need to show the ID field in the Edit Form of a sharepoint list.

There is a way to do it ? I tried a calculated field and nothing.
I know that I can see the ID field in the view, and if I show as a Access Mode.
I'm using WSS3.0

Comment: Are you creating your list via the front end, or a list definition feature? Is a custom edit form an option for you?

Comment: Creating it via front end. Yes, a custom edit form is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [add the ID field to the form using some JavaScript in a CEWP](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/showing-the-records-id-on-the-view-and-edit-forms/).

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
  // Get the ID from the query string
  var id = getQueryString()["ID"];

  // Find the form's main table
  var table = $('table.ms-formtable');

  // Add a row with the ID in
  table.prepend("<tr><td class='ms-formlabel'><h3 class='ms-standardheader'>ID</h3></td>" +
                "<td class='ms-formbody'>" + id + "&nbsp;</td></tr>");
})

function getQueryString() {
  var assoc = new Array();
  var queryString = unescape(location.search.substring(1));
  var keyValues = queryString.split('&');
  for (var i in keyValues) {
    var key = keyValues[i].split('=');
    assoc[key[0]] = key[1];
    }
  return assoc;
}
</script>
```

There is an alternative [method that doesn't use the jQuery library](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/01/18/item-id-in-display-and-edit-forms/) if you prefer to keep things lightweight.

Comment: Thank's Ryan. That's it. Very easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a custom edit form quite easily. I usually stick it into an HTML table rendered within a webpart. There may be a better way of doing that but it's simple and it works.

The key line you'll want to look at is spFormField.ControlMode. This tells SharePoint how to display the control (Invalid, Display, Edit, New). So what you'll want to do is check if your spField.InternalName == "ID" and if it is, set the ControlMode to be Display.

The rest is just fluff for rendering the rest of the list.

Hope this helps.

```
HtmlTable hTable = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableRow hRow = new HtmlTableRow();
HtmlTableCell hCellLabel = new HtmlTableCell();
HtmlTableCell hCellControl = new HtmlTableCell();
SPWeb spWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

// Get the list we are going to work with
SPList spList = spWeb.Lists["MyList"];

// Loop through the fields
foreach (SPField spField in spList.Fields)
{
   // See if this field is not hidden or hide/show based on your own criteria
   if (!spField.Hidden && !spField.ReadOnlyField && spField.Type != SPFieldType.Attachments && spField.StaticName != "ContentType")
   {
     // Create the label field
     FieldLabel spLabelField = new FieldLabel();
     spLabelField.ControlMode = _view; 
     spLabelField.ListId = spList.ID;
     spLabelField.FieldName = spField.StaticName;

     // Create the form field
     FormField spFormField = new FormField();

// Begin: this is your solution here.
     if (spField.InteralName == "ID")
     { spFormField.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display; }
     else
     { spFormField.ControlMode = _view; }
// End: the end of your solution.

     spFormField.ListId = spList.ID;
     spFormField.FieldName = spField.InternalName;

     // Add the table row
     hRow = new HtmlTableRow();
     hTable.Rows.Add(hRow);

     // Add the cells
     hCellLabel = new HtmlTableCell();
     hRow.Cells.Add(hCellLabel);
     hCellControl = new HtmlTableCell();
     hRow.Cells.Add(hCellControl);

     // Add the control to the table cells
     hCellLabel.Controls.Add(spLabelField);
     hCellControl.Controls.Add(spFormField);

     // Set the css class of the cell for the SharePoint styles
     hCellLabel.Attributes["class"] = "ms-formlabel";
     hCellControl.Attributes["class"] = "ms-formbody";
   }
```

}